# ConTeXt: How to make table of contents to show only those entries which go after its placement?

Tags: table-of-contents, context, context-mkiv

```
\setuplist
[chapter][
  style={bold},
  color={default},
]

\setuplist
[section]
[color={default}]

\setuplist
[subsection]
[color={default}]

\setuplist
[title][
  style={bold},
  color={default},
]

\setupcombinedlist
[content][
  alternative={c},
         list={chapter, section, subsection, title},
]

...

\starttitle
[title={Annotation}]
  ...
\stoptitle

\starttitle
[title={Table of Contents}]
  \placecontent
\stoptitle

\starttitle
[title={Introduction}]
  ...
\stoptitle

\startchapter
[title={My Chapter}]
  ...
\stopchapter

...

\starttitle
[title={References}]
  ...
\stoptitle
```

I don't want table of contents to show **Annotation** and **Table of Contents** entries, but rather only those that go after its placement, e.g. **Introduction**, **My Chapter**, and **References**. This style is quite typical, but I haven't found any options related to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnumbered sections aren’t shown in the table of contents unless you set `\setuphead[...][incrementnumber=list]` in your document.

To restrict the entries in the table of contents two methods are possible, the first method is to create a new heading which isn’t in the `content` list.

```
\definehead[topic][title]
\setuphead [title][incrementnumber=list]

\setupcombinedlist
  [content]
  [list={chapter,title,section,subsection}]

\starttext

\starttopic[title={Annotation}]
  ...
\stoptopic

\starttopic[title={Table of Contents}]
  \placecontent
\stoptopic

\starttitle[title={Introduction}]
  ...
\stoptitle

\startchapter[title={My Chapter}]
  ...
\stopchapter

\starttitle[title={References}]
  ...
\stoptitle

\stoptext
```

The second method is two divide your document in section blocks and set the `incrementnumber` key at the begin of the `bodypart`. The `\startsectionblockenvironment` command stores all setups until the begin of the corresponding block.

```
\startsectionblockenvironment[bodypart]
  \setuphead[title][incrementnumber=list]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\setupcombinedlist
  [content]
  [list={chapter,title,section,subsection}]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter

\starttitle[title={Annotation}]
  ...
\stoptitle

\starttitle[title={Table of Contents}]
  \placecontent
\stoptitle

\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter

\starttitle[title={Introduction}]
  ...
\stoptitle

\startchapter[title={My Chapter}]
  ...
\stopchapter

\starttitle[title={References}]
  ...
\stoptitle

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

You can also slightly modify this method and set for `\placecontent` command from which sectionblock you want the stored entries, to do this change the command to

```
\placecontent[criterium=bodypart:all]
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! You seem to know quite a lot about ConTeXt internals. Out of curiosity, are you just a power user or a developer?